# Blazor Server and Font Awesome: Svgs not being replaced after initial load

Tags: font-awesome, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I'm running into an issue where my font awesome icons are not updating after the initial load. The  tags are being replaced to svg, but it will always the initial font awesome icon / svg and as I navigate and the data updates, the svc is not being replaced in Blazor Server.

I've found 3 articles, but they do not seem to help:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51696

[Icon not updating when sorting with Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71326145/icon-not-updating-when-sorting-with-blazor)

https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/12556#issuecomment-619571925

I'm using .net 8 Core/Blazor Server.

I'm using a SyncFusion SfCard, but I've already put a ticket into their support and this is not on their side.

Any ideas of what I'm missing?

Here is where I'm pulling the files for font awesome from:

https://fontawesome.com/download => 6.5.1 For The Web => all.min.js

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet />
@*     <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes/bootstrap5.css" /> *@
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Themes/fluent.css" />
    <script src="_content/Syncfusion.Blazor.Core/scripts/syncfusion-blazor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/localStorage.js"></script>
    <script src="js/logoutOnly.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fontawesome/all.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Initial load image -> Shows toolbox as it should

[image]

Clicking View it changes my title and my description but the icon stays a toolbox even though it should be a gear

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (MenuItemInfoModel? item in FilteredMenuData)
        {
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <SfCard @ref="sfCard" CssClass="card mb-3">
                    <CardHeader Title="@item.Name">
                    </CardHeader>
                    <CardContent>
                        <i class="@item.IconTxt fa-2x" data-prefix="fas"></i>
                        @item.IconTxt
                   @*      <SfIcon IconCss="@item.IconTxt" Size="Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons.IconSize.Medium"></SfIcon>
@* @*                         <SfIcon Name="@GetIconName(item.IconTxt ?? "Home")" Size="Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons.IconSize.Large"></SfIcon> *@ 
                        @item.DescriptionTxt
                    </CardContent>
                    <CardFooter>
                        <CardFooterContent>
                            <SfButton CssClass="e-btn e-outline e-primary" Content="View" @onclick="(args) => onToggleClick(args, item)">
                            </SfButton>
                        </CardFooterContent>
                    </CardFooter>
                </SfCard>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue I had to go with using the classes instead of SVGs.

1. Remove the reference to font awesome javascript
2. Add the webfonts from the font awesome web download in the proper order
3. Make sure the stylesheet reference in my App.razor was correct to the correct folder structure

Using free version of font awesome 6.5.1

My understanding is the Blazor life cycle does not include functionality to update the SVG since that is completed in the font awesome javascript file etc.

[image]